# Doctrine Many to Many

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, many-to-many

I have a question about Doctrine ORM M:M.
I built some tables like this:
-User
+id
+name
-Group
+id
+name

I want to link these table via a new table with Doctrine:
In Group class:

```
$this->hasMany('User as Users', array(
            // I'm wondering what I can fill here
            'refClass' => 'UserGroup'
        ));
```

and in the User class:

```
 $this->hasMany('Group as Groups', array(
                // I'm wondering what I can fill here
                'refClass' => 'UserGroup'
            ));
```

Please help me fill the blank. Thanks.
Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

P/S:Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

There is some nice documentation for this at http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/defining-models#relationships:join-table-associations:many-to-many servicing exactly your model.

Basically this code in the User table class:

```
$this->hasMany('Group as Groups', array(
                'local' => 'user_id',
                'foreign' => 'group_id',
                'refClass' => 'UserGroup'
            )
        );
```

states that the Group table is related, via the UserGroup intersection table. The "user_id" column in UserGroup is the key that matches the local table (User) and "group_id" is the key that matches in the foreign table (Group).

A similar statement in the Group table class provides the reverse:

```
$this->hasMany('User', array(
                'foreign' => 'user_id',
                'local' => 'group_id',
                'refClass' => 'UserGroup'
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Group:

```
$this->hasMany('User as Users', array(
  'refClass' => 'UserGroup',
  'local' => 'group_id',
  'foreign' => 'user_id');
```

User:

```
$this->hasMany('Group as Groups', array(
  'refClass' => 'UserGroup',
  'local' => 'user_id',
  'foreign' => 'group_id');
```